# Java - setting Fonts/Color in setBorder

Tags: java, swing, fonts, colors, jpanel

Is there a way I can define my own font and color schemes for Text1 AND Text2 text 
within the setBorder method. New to java and cannot find it in the SUN tutorials.

My code

```
//Create Positions Table
 JPanel SpreadPanel = new JPanel();
 SpreadPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Text 1    Text 2"));
```

Regards
Simon

Comment: Please refer to [`API`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html)

Answer (score 8):

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "text", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.BOTTOM, new Font("times new roman",Font.PLAIN,12), Color.yellow));
```

the first parameter null or another border (for compound borders)
2nd param  text that you're displaying
3rd and 4th param   justification and location of the text from param 2

4th param 
and 5th param are the two to set font and color

Answer (score 3):

If you want a *different* font and color for each of the strings (e.g. `Text1` and `Text2`) in the *same* `TitledBorder`, you may be need to extend [`AbstractBorder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/AbstractBorder.html) and override `paintBorder()`. The existing implementation only has one font and one color for a single title.

Answer (score 1):

Text Font:

```
((javax.swing.border.TitledBorder) panel_1.getBorder()).setTitleFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
```

Text Color:

```
((javax.swing.border.TitledBorder)panel_1.getBorder()).setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDocs for doing this are somewhat overwhelming if you are new to Java and Swing. The JavaDocs for BorderFactory are here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html

Here's an example of making the text red in a sans serif font:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Font myFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        Color myColor = Color.RED;
        TitledBorder titledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, " Text 1    Text 2", TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, myFont, myColor);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello gruel world");
        label.setBorder(titledBorder);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question. 
Thought I would like to resurrect it as maybe someone knows how to solve this problem. I have only 'a partial solution'.

I have very quickly implemented the border which does what you want. I have reused what Java gives, i.e. interpretation of HTML in swing components.

All works sweet, the border is painted fine for a plain or HTML text, with exception for a situation where you are trying to have different font sizes for the texts.

I do not have idea how to solve this issue. But I am very much interested in a solution.

I know the procedure would be to sum up width of each string in its own font size when calculating the textLengthInPixels variable.

**The problem is** that I do not know how to get it, maybe from the View, but no idea how?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.View;

public class MultiColorTitleBorder extends AbstractBorder
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel label;
    private int thicknessTop = 10;
    private Border border;
    private int thicknessLeft = 0;
    private int thicknessRight = 0;
    private int thicknessBottom = 0;

    public MultiColorTitleBorder(String title)
    {
        this.label = new JLabel(title);
        thicknessTop = label.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    public MultiColorTitleBorder(String title, Border border)
    {
        this(title);
        this.border = border;
        thicknessLeft = border.getBorderInsets(null).left;
        thicknessRight = border.getBorderInsets(null).right;
        thicknessBottom = border.getBorderInsets(null).bottom;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        View view = (View) label.getClientProperty("html");
        String text = label.getText();
        FontMetrics fm = g2.getFontMetrics(label.getFont());
        int bY = y + fm.getAscent() - ((fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent())) / 2;

        if(border != null)
        {
            Insets in = border.getBorderInsets(c);
            g2.setClip(x, y, thicknessLeft * 2, height);
            border.paintBorder(c, g, x, bY, width, height - bY);
            try
            {
                if(view != null)
                    text = view.getDocument().getText(0, view.getDocument().getLength());
            }catch(BadLocationException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MultiColorTitleBorder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            int textLengthInPixels = fm.stringWidth(text);
            System.out.println("textLengthInPixels=" + textLengthInPixels);
            g2.setClip(x +thicknessLeft * 2+ textLengthInPixels, y, width - thicknessLeft * 2 -textLengthInPixels, height);
            border.paintBorder(c, g, x, bY, width, height - bY);
            int bottomIn = in.bottom;
            g2.setClip(x, height - bottomIn, width, bottomIn);
            border.paintBorder(c, g, x, bY, width, height - bY);
            g2.setClip(x, y, width, height);
        }
        if(view != null)
            view.paint(g2, new Rectangle(x + thicknessLeft * 2, y, width - thicknessLeft * 2, height));
        else
        {
            Font prevFont = g2.getFont();
            g2.setFont(label.getFont());
            g2.drawString(text, x + thicknessLeft * 2, fm.getAscent());
            g2.setFont(prevFont);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c)
    {
        return new Insets(thicknessTop, thicknessLeft, thicknessBottom, thicknessRight);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets)
    {
        insets.top = thicknessTop;
        insets.left = thicknessLeft;
        insets.right = thicknessRight;
        insets.bottom = thicknessBottom;
        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        String title = "<html><color=red> Text 1</font><font color=blue>      Text 2</font>";
        //title = "<html><font color=red font size=5> Text 1</font><font color=blue>      Text 2</font>";
        //title = "Text 1   Text 2";

        p.setBorder(new MultiColorTitleBorder(title, new LineBorder(Color.CYAN, 6)));
        p.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        p.add(new JTextField(5));
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(p);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(contentPane);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));
```